# Create onClickListener() in more than 1 thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

Can I create `onClickListener()` for a button in more than 1 threads that are executing simultaneously?

Would that listener be called individually in every thread?

Comment: More than 1 thread, you cannot do it since Button are run only in the main thread thus must only have 1 onclicklistener.

Comment: yes @gabe-sechan has already said that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a button has only one onClickListener.  Setting a second one overwrites any listener set previously.  And that function will only be called on the UI thread.  You can pass messages to multiple threads from that function though.

Comment: Yes how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to communicate between threads. Since you are wondering how to pass something over to the thread, here is a simple example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        //Start a thread you need to
        anotherThread = new AnotherThread();
        anotherThread.start();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        ...
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                anotherThread.sendData(message);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class AnotherThread extends Thread {
    //Instantiate handler to associate it with the current thread.
    //Handler enqueues all tasks in the MessageQueue using Looper
    //and execute them upon coming out of queue;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Here we create a unique Looper for this thread.
            //The main purpose of which to keep thread alive looping through
            //MessageQueue and send task to corresponding handler.
            Looper.prepare();
            handler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    //manage incoming messages here
                    String value = msg.getData().getString("key");
                }
            };
            Looper.loop();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void sendData(Message message) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*To get more about thread communication I'd recommend you the following:*
[1](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html), [2](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a#.w0okeir75), [3](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/).